# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'. Error after publish

Tags: c#

I am saving Image in a database. It works great  when I Debug it. , but after publish it and I try to load or try to save the picture it gives me type cast error.
I am using following code to save image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
kephelye.Image.Save(ms, kephelye.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
```

and load image:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
byte[] ap = (byte[])(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["kepcim"]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ap);
if (ms.Length != 0) {
 kephelye2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}

ms.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["kepcim"]` is a byte array?..

Comment: There might be a mismatch between the table layout of your test database and your production database.

Comment: Thanks it was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the image from the memory stream into a new bitmap, and close the stream.

```
public static Image GetImage(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, offset, count);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(memoryStream));
    // Close the stream here, won't affect the bitmap.
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I solved the problem :) There was a mismatch because in the database the "kepcime"-column was STRING not BLOB :)